# How to check message arrival in service bus at every 20 seconds?

Tags: c#, azure, scheduled-tasks, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am using **Service Bus** of azure which will hold my list of messages means messages can enter in service bus at any time.

So i want to keep a watch on my service bus to check that whether any message is there in service or not.It is like i just want to keep a watch on my service bus regarding message arrival in my service bus at interval 0f 20 seconds.

In Every 20 Seconds i would like to check message arrival in my service bus and this i want to perform in background asynchronously.

I want to call below method in every 20 seconds in background:

```
 private static void ReceiveMessages()
        {
            // For PeekLock mode (default) where applications require "at least once" delivery of messages 
            SubscriptionClient agentSubscriptionClient = SubscriptionClient.Create(TopicName, "AgentSubscription");
            BrokeredMessage message = null;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    //receive messages from Agent Subscription
                    message = agentSubscriptionClient.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    if (message != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nReceiving message from AgentSubscription...");
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message received: Id = {0}, Body = {1}", message.MessageId, message.GetBody<string>()));
                        // Further custom message processing could go here...
                        message.Complete();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //no more messages in the subscription
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (MessagingException e)
                {
                    if (!e.IsTransient)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        throw;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HandleTransientErrors(e);
                    }
                }
            }

            // For ReceiveAndDelete mode, where applications require "best effort" delivery of messages
            SubscriptionClient auditSubscriptionClient = SubscriptionClient.Create(TopicName, "AuditSubscription", ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    message = auditSubscriptionClient.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    if (message != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nReceiving message from AuditSubscription...");
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message received: Id = {0}, Body = {1}", message.MessageId, message.GetBody<string>()));
                        // Further custom message processing could go here...
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nno more messages in the subscription");
                        //no more messages in the subscription
                        break;
                    }

                }
                catch (MessagingException e)
                {
                    if (!e.IsTransient)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }

            agentSubscriptionClient.Close();
            auditSubscriptionClient.Close();
        }
```

So can anybody tell me how do i call this above method every 20 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

The most beginner-friendly solution is:

Drag a Timer from the Toolbox, give it a Name, set your desired Interval and set "Enabled" to True. Then double click the Timer and Visual Studio (or whatever you are using) will write you the following Code:

```
private void wait_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    refreshText(); //add the method you want to call here.
}
```

or this

```
private Timer timer1; 
public void InitTimer()
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 2000; // in miliseconds
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isonline()
}
```